# Not able to vagrant up with homestead

Tags: laravel, homestead, laravel-8

I'm trying to get homestead to work on my windows 10 machine, but after installing vagrant and virtual box I'm getting this error

```
Bringing machine 'homestead' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> homestead: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' version '9.5.1' is up to date...
==> homestead: A newer version of the box 'laravel/homestead' is available and already
==> homestead: installed, but your Vagrant machine is running against
==> homestead: version '9.5.1'. To update to version '9.7.2',
==> homestead: destroy and recreate your machine.
==> homestead: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> homestead: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> homestead: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    homestead: Adapter 1: nat
    homestead: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> homestead: Forwarding ports...
    homestead: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead: 443 (guest) => 44300 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead: 3306 (guest) => 33060 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead: 4040 (guest) => 4040 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead: 5432 (guest) => 54320 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead: 8025 (guest) => 8025 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead: 9600 (guest) => 9600 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead: 27017 (guest) => 27017 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> homestead: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> homestead: Booting VM...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "33155129-8efb-4194-a2e3-394aa799b6ab", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2' (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND).
VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to attach the network LUN (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole
```

Comment: Have you tried running it as an administrator?

Comment: That didn't work either

Comment: find one similar issue  see this discussion https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=94277

Answer (score 0):

it seems the problem is in network adapter, check the network adapter settings of your virtual machine.

Comment: For my adapter 1 I have Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop (NAT) and for adapter 2 I have Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop (Host-only Adapter, 'VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2')